# Can anyone tell me how I can change the Open With listing on a Mac?

Tags: finder, ms-office

Do you guys know how to have the ***Open With*** show the newer version of a program rather than the older version? For example, I have Office 2011 on my computer and if I do ***Open With*** the Excel verison that shows in the list is the 2008 version. I would prefer it to show the 2011 version. I am hoping that I don't have to delete the Office 2008 suite so if there is something else I can do to update the ***Open With*** listing that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mouse to try opening the file again.

- Choose **Open With…**
- Then select **Other…**
- Check the box at the bottom labeled **Always Open With**.

before you select the application you want to now open that file type or extension.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I do know about that. :) I was just hoping to have the program listed as a default in the Open With listing so that I didn't have to go to so many steps every time with new files.

Comment: It is very complicated to inject a new program into the list and then override the mapping. In practice, the system generally picks the best app and you only have to over-rule it once per type. Since you're new - we have a guide at http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask that goes over some basics of asking. Until you list what you tried and why it didn't work, we can only guess your level. If you search this site for `lsregister` you can see some other options for managing the launch services database which controls this list.

Comment: Thanks Bmike.  I didn't realize it would be a complicated request and would have hoped that a MAC would show the newest program version in the Open With listing. ;)

Comment: Didn't mean to enter that so quickly.  Also wanted to add, appreciate the offering you suggested.  Best.

Comment: As a follow up, I have gone ahead and deleted the old version of my Excel and the Open With does now default with the new version.  Cheers all.

Comment: Excellent news. Getting rid of the old version has many benefits including not needing to know any of the above :).